# 8's complement of a fractional octal value

Tags: octal, number-systems

Well the question is that I have to perform an octal subtraction using 8's complement method. The question is like this: `(611.21)base 8 - (304.42)base 8`. Subtraction part is fine but the problem comes when taking the 8's complement of the number. After you calculate the 7's complement i.e. (473.35)base 8, we add 1 to make it 8's complement. My doubt is that 1 is simply to be added or 1 is to be added to the rightmost digit.

Because according to the method by GeeksForGeeks,

> To find b’s complement, just add 1 to the calculated (b-1)’s complement.

By doing so, the answer to my answer of subtraction is coming (474.35)base 8 , but if you do the subtraction in the normal way (without 8's complement method), the answer comes out to be (304.57)base 8.

I have looked for the solution at so many places but I am still in a dilemma of what's the correct one.

To summarise my points, I would like to ask that when finding 8's complement of a fractional octal value, we simply add 1 to the 7's complement or do we add 1 to the rightmost bit of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let **N** be a number in **base b**, having an **integer part of n digits** and **fractional part of m digits**. When you take a **b's complement**, you are essentially **subtracting that number from b^n** i.e. ***b^n - N***. This is intuitive even when you have a fractional part in N.

Things become slightly different when you have to deal with  **(b-1)'s complement**. The case is fairly simple when you have to deal with integers. You just **subtract the number from b^n - 1**. So if you want the 9's complement of 8 it would be 9 - 8 = 1 or if you want 10's complement it is 10 - 8 = 9 - 8 + 1 = 2, and this is what you claim, **To find b’s complement, just add 1 to the calculated (b-1)’s complement**. This however holds only when the numbers don't have a fractional part. We extend the idea of subtracting 1 to go from base b complement to base b-1 complement to the fractional part, so if you want the 9's complement of 8.1 you have to subtract 8.1 from 9.9 and not just 9. Generalizing this idea, **(b-1)'s complement** is defined to be ***(b^n - b^-m) - N***. From here you can easily find out that **for integers,
b's complement - (b-1)'s complement = b^n - N - ((b^n - b^-0) - N) = b^0 = 1.**

TLDR;

When finding 8's complement of a fractional octal value, we simply add 1 to the 7's complement or do we add 1 to the rightmost bit of the answer, both of them mean the same as long as you only have to deal with integers. With fractions, **you add it to the rightmost bit of the fractional part.** This can be proved in a similar way as above.